# Resize the width and height of shape (not scaling) in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

How can I implement the resizing of width and height of a shape in paper js. just like this : [Resizing Objects in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186237/resizing-objects-in-fabric-js) ? I am currently basing on this link : [Transform bounding box in Paper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785966/transform-bounding-box-in-paper-js) .

Comment: The working link in the thread you mentioned is not good enough for you?

Comment: No. Because the scaling is from the center. I need to scale the width / height.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented it in [Romanesco](http://romanesco.io/) but it is a bit complicated (I still have to clean the code).

Maybe you would go faster by doing it yourself.

Anyway you can have a look in the source code, in [SelectionRectangle.coffee](https://github.com/arthursw/romanesco-client-code/blob/master/coffee/View/SelectionRectangle.coffee), [SelectTool.coffe](https://github.com/arthursw/romanesco-client-code/blob/master/coffee/Tools/SelectTool.coffee) and [Item.coffee](https://github.com/arthursw/romanesco-client-code/blob/master/coffee/Items/Item.coffee).